# Cucumber scenario with same buttons?

Tags: cucumber

This is my first time doing cucumber, so maybe what im asking isn't wrong but it just seems like there is a better way:

So right now im going through a survey-like website as my first automation task with cucumber. It works just fine, but like most surveys theirs a lot of "Fill then out, then click Next"

so in my Feature file I have a lot of:

```
    Then I will click 'Next'
```

Which matches with the step (Since the button all have the same text):

```
Then(/^I will click 'Next'$/) do
  click_button('Next')
end
```

So this one step definition defines like 8-9 lines in my feature file...which I guess is ok, but my feature file just looks...ugly? Im not used to the Gherkin language AT ALL as this is my first time, but it's basically turned into a lot of:

```
THEN SELECT THAT THING FROM DROPDOWN
THEN CLICK THIS RADIO BUTTON
THEN SELECT THIS BUTTON
THEN CLICK NEXT
```

Like over and over....I mean it's human readable, but it just looks messy? is this right?

Also im not really sure when I should use "explicits" in my feature file? Like should I explicity say Im going to select 'X' (or "X", not sure if it matters) from a dropdown? or Click the 'Next' button or select the 'yes' radio button for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing what are called imperative steps and it is indeed the wrong way to go about cucumber/gherkin.

Your steps should be saying "WHAT" you are doing and not "HOW" you are doing.

Not knowing the details of your form, let's make up a flow.
Page 1. Name
Page 2. Demographics
Page 3. Favorite football team
Page 4. Favorite basketball team
Page 5. Results page showing how popular their teams with other survey takers

```
Given I enter the "Are you a Bandwagon Fan Survey"
When I enter my name
And I enter my demographics
And I choose a favorite football team
And I choose a favorite basketball team
Then I should be directed to the result page
And I should see my teams ranked on a graph
```

The details for entering your name and clicking next should be hidden inside that stepdef. A person trying to test your app doesn't care what the name is, or what the field ID is or anything like that. They just want to know the work flow.

If you are doing scenarios to get the name page to error you simply modify your gherkin to say something like.

```
When I enter a name too long
Then I see a name too long error message

When I do not enter a name
Then I see a name missing error message
```

Again, you leave the details of too long or what the error message is to the step def (or below) unless it is critically important to the test scenario. I usually set up factory girls to handle my data and just use the text of the scenario to pull the current data. so I'll have an error message factory and within that a "name_missing" and a "name_too_long" sub-factory that provide the correct values. If I need to change or look something up, everything is in the same place...but above all it's not cluttering my gherkin.

Comment: I figured I was doing it wrong lol. but hey first time.... But this is excelent information! thank you.

Also what is the difference between AND and THEN as far as cucumber is concerned? Im assuming they are both 'keywords'?

Comment: Also im guessing I should avoid using specific identifiers IE: "Then I select 'OPTION A' from dropdown, I should instead say: Then I select an option from the Choose Option dropdown? Also not saying you are wrong, but why is writing cucumber Imperatively bad? It seems more descriptive? Isn't that a good thing...?

Comment: "And" is just saying I am continuing my Given/When/Then. It has no real meaning on it's own. Given is usually the test setup/prep, When is the action being tested and Then is the expected result of the action. Technical suff: In ruby cucumber Given/When/Then are actually ignored. They are all aliases of Cucumber::RbSupport::RbDSL#register_rb_step_definition and cucumber ignores the keyword in matching regular expressions. They are only there to help you express the intent of the step.

Comment: Awesome, I remade the test in a more declarative fashion, and it does look better (hiding multiple instances of clicking "next" multiple times, which IMO doesn't need to be seen). Looked a lot better for sure (and was a good bit shorter for the feature file)

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think you want to send parameters to step definition

```
Then I will click 'Next'
```

Step definition will be

```
Then(/^I will click "([^"]*))*"$/) do |text|
  click_button(text)
end
```

also above will work for

```
Then I will click 'OK'
```

Comment: Right, but im saying alot of the buttons say 'Next' to continue to the next screen, so im wondering if it makes sense to just keep saying "Then Click 'Next'" or if I should be more descriptive

Comment: no you do nt have to descriptive just use the text whatever it is